# Filter NSLog data

Tags: ios, cocoa, nslog

I would like to filter NSLog for getting the only information I need. 
My NSLog gives me :

```
Birthday : 05/24/1993
Id : xxxxxx (number)
```

I want to keep only 05/24/1993, is there any solution?

My code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me?fields=birthday"];
    [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result, NSError *error) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:result forKey:@"birthdayDate"];
        self.birthdayArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"birthdayDate"];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"birthdayDate contains[c] /"];
        self.birthday = [self.birthdayArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        NSLog(@"BIRTHDAY : %@", self.birthday);

    }
```

Comment: what is the object you are printing?

Comment: Where do you want to filter the log output? While running your app through Xcode in debug mode? Xcode doesn't provide any filtering of the console output.

Comment: @Andrey Chernukha It's a FBRequest with Graph API : (FBRequestConnection *connection,id result, NSError *error)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I've edited my code, I've found how to store Facebook data in NSArray (in code), but my NSPredicate doesn't work. I want to be able to keep only the birthday date in the NSArray "birthday" cf code.